# xslt sum node values where node value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XSLT file that is collecting information from an XML document, and then presenting it out to a CSV file.

Presenting all of the information works fine, however what I need to do now is to sum all information of a node i:totalDurationInSeconds where i:issueBatchNumber = D12345

This is the code I have so far

```
<xsl:template match="/">

<Textblock>Batch Number,Formula Code,Formula Name,Material Code,Material Name,Final Weight, Target Weight, Date, Material Weight, Job Name, Started At, Finished At</Textblock>
<xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
<xsl:variable name ="BatchIds" select="//i:issues/i:issue"/>

<!-- begin for each loop -->
<xsl:for-each select="$BatchIds">
  <xsl:variable name="currentPosition" select="position()"/>
  <xsl:variable name="nextPosition" select="position()+1"/>
  <xsl:variable name="lastPosition" select="position()-1" />
  <xsl:variable name="lastBatchId" select="//i:issues/i:issue[$lastPosition]/i:issueBatchNumber"/>
  <xsl:variable name="thisBatchId" select="i:issueBatchNumber" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not($lastBatchId = $thisBatchId)" >
      <xsl:variable name="startingBatchId" select="//i:issues/i:issue[1]/i:issueBatchNumber"/>
      Batch ID: <xsl:value-of select="i:issueBatchNumber"/><xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
      Total Time in Seconds: <sum value here -- this is the bit I dont know how to do>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise >

    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  outputting csv data here
</xsl:for-each>
```

This is a sample of the xml Data I am working with

```
<issues>
 <issue>
  <weight>0.903999984264374</weight>
  <materialBatch>
    <Code>WB821</materialCode>
    <weight>0</weight>
    <cost>0</cost>
  </materialBatch>
  <issueBatchNumber>D15601001</issueBatchNumber>
  <jobNumber>Default Job 2015-4</jobNumber>
  <date>2015-04-30T02:36:47</date>
  <dateStarted>2015-04-30T02:33:38</dateStarted>
  <finishedAt>2015-04-30T02:36:03</finishedAt>
  <dispenseDurationInSeconds>144.78</dispenseDurationInSeconds>
 </issue>
     <issue>
  <weight>0.903999984264374</weight>
  <materialBatch>
    <Code>WB821</materialCode>
    <weight>0</weight>
    <cost>0</cost>
  </materialBatch>
  <issueBatchNumber>D15601001</issueBatchNumber>
  <jobNumber>Default Job 2015-4</jobNumber>
  <date>2015-04-30T02:36:47</date>
  <dateStarted>2015-04-30T02:36:03</dateStarted>
  <finishedAt>2015-04-30T02:49.33</finishedAt>
  <dispenseDurationInSeconds>13.3</dispenseDurationInSeconds>
 </issue>
     <issue>
  <weight>0.903999984264374</weight>
  <materialBatch>
    <Code>WB821</materialCode>
    <weight>0</weight>
    <cost>0</cost>
  </materialBatch>
  <issueBatchNumber>D15601001</issueBatchNumber>
  <jobNumber>Default Job 2015-4</jobNumber>
  <date>2015-04-30T02:36:47</date>
  <dateStarted>2015-04-30T02:49.33</dateStarted>
  <finishedAt>2015-04-30T02:54.22</finishedAt>
  <dispenseDurationInSeconds>5.99</dispenseDurationInSeconds>
 </issue>
</issues>
```

Comment: Please provide an input XML, update the XSLT to be complete, an output(CSV), and then try explaining the problem.

Comment: I have added a sample of the XML input, the CSV output is coming out fine, its the summing over the dispenseDurationInSeconds that I need help with as explained above

Comment: where is the node you want to sum on, can't see it in your sample, so hard to answer.
Is this something like this you're looking for : sum(*[i:issueBatchNumber = D12345]/i:totalDurationInSeconds). But without more details it's more or less a complete guess...

Comment: Hi Eric, yes, thats the kind of thing I am looking for.. I will try that and se what I get

Comment: I get a value of 0 using this, which is the result ive been getting all morning so far. in the data im working with there are 3 values i need add together  144.10, 13.3 and 5.99

Comment: Do you mean to sum all of `dispenseDurationInSeconds`? (because I can't see anything like `totalDurationInSeconds` in your sample XML)

Comment: @SimonPrice please put those 3 values you need to sum (`144.10, 13.3 and 5.99`) in your sample XML, so we have clear idea of where they are located

Comment: edited to show what I am trying to calculate against

Comment: This is still quite confusing. If you want CSV output, why are you creating XML elements? And if you are creating  a row for each issue, then where is the sum supposed to go? Should there be only one sum in the entire output? And should it include only certain, predefined  issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
<xsl:value-of 
    select="sum(../i:issue[i:issueBatchNumber=$thisBatchId]/i:dispenseDurationInSeconds)">
```

above xpath return sum of all `dispenseDurationInSeconds` from parent `issue` elements having child `issueBatchNumber` equals current `$thisBatchId` value.